# How can I reinitialize heads from tracking branches in git config?

Tags: git

If I run,

```
$ git branch -t 86 upstream/86
Branch '86' set up to track remote branch '86' from 'upstream'.
```

I can see that two things happen

- an entry is added to `.git/config`

  ```
  [branch "86"]
      remote = upstream
      merge = refs/heads/86
  ```
- a ref file is created for the corresponding branch, `./.git/refs/heads/86`

If I delete this file, `./.git/refs/heads/86` is the remaining entry in the `.git/config` of any use? Is there any command I can run to recreate all of the heads (files in the directory)? Or must I rerun all of the commands that I originally ran to create them?

Comment: Rarely is there a good reason to modify anything inside the `.git` directory. What is your goal?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I'm using ansible to provision git config files with remote tracking information, and this is the only case where putting stuff inside the config file is not sufficient because of a synchronization issue between the git config and the remote refs. So i want to recreate the remote refs from the .gitconfig.

Comment: "*provision git config files with remote tracking information*" Wrong approach IMO. Instead of fiddling with `.git/config` you'd better run necessary `git` commands.

Comment: The Git authors feel somewhat free to change the internal structure of branch names, and have already done so once with the introduction of "packed" refs. There may never be a `.git/refs/heads/86` someday.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got that branch checked out, `git reset --soft origin/86` will do (`--soft` does only the `HEAD` update, the default reset, `--mixed`, also reloads the index entries; `--hard` additionally resets the work tree).

If you don't (or either way, really, this works regardless), it's core-command time:   `git update-ref refs/heads/86 origin/86`.

edit: to do this in a batch you can generate update commands from the config entries, `git update-ref` has  a `--stdin` argument and a little command interpreter for doing bulk updates.

> I'm using ansible to provision git config files with remote tracking information, and this is the only case where putting stuff inside the config file is not sufficient because of a synchronization issue between the git config and the remote refs. So i want to recreate the remote refs from the .gitconfig.

That should have been your lead paragraph.

It's reasonable to assume you're using the standard refspecs, `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/$remote/*`, slightly less reasonable to assume everything's coming from `origin`, but I'll leave generalizing this to multiple remotes or custom refspecs as an exercise for the reader:

```
git config --get-regexp ^branch\..*\..merge \
| awk -F'[. /]' '{print "update refs/heads/"$2" origin/"$NF}' \
| git update-ref --stdin
```

To actually create the *remote* refs, you have to run `git fetch`, going through `git ls-remote` and creating the refs manually won't help if you don't have the objects.

Comment: I don't want to run a command for every branch that lacks a ref entry in the directory.

Comment: You have to generate the list somehow, what's hard about generating commands? Is your question not just about repairing damage, but also about figuring out what damage has been done?

Comment: @jthill : branch names may themselves contain '/' or '.' characters. I would replace the 'awk ...' part with a more straigthforward sed, which would search and replace target patterns.

Comment: @jthill : also, in the OP, the remote is named "upstream", not "origin"